# mysql syntax error in creating new table near ', thalrest INT, tpeakbps INT, tpeakbpd INT, dummy INT, trestbpd INT, exang INT,'

Tags: mysql

I have a new mysql database with no existing tables and I am trying to create a new one called original. My code is as follows (apologies for the painfully long code segment, I'm assuming more information is better):

```
CREATE TABLE original (
    id INT,
    ccf INT,
    age INT,
    sex INT,
    painloc INT,
    painexer INT,
    relrest INT,
    pncaden INT,
    cp INT,
    trestbps INT,
    htn INT,
    chol INT,
    smoke INT,
    cigs INT,
    years INT,
    fbs INT,
    dm INT,
    famhist INT,
    restecg INT,
    ekgmo INT,
    ekgday INT,
    ekgyr INT,
    dig INT,
    prop INT,
    nitr INT,
    pro INT,
    diuretic INT,
    proto INT,
    thaldur INT,
    thaltime INT,
    met INT,
    thalach INT,
    thalrest INT,
    tpeakbps INT,
    tpeakbpd INT,
    dummy INT,
    trestbpd INT,
    exang INT,
    xhypo INT,
    oldpeak INT,
    slope INT,
    rldv5 INT,
    rldv5e INT,
    ca INT,
    restckm INT,
    exerckm INT,
    restef INT,
    restwm INT,
    exeref INT,
    exerwm INT,
    thal INT,
    thalsev INT,
    thalpul INT,
    earlobe INT,
    cmo INT,
    cday INT,
    cyr INT,
    num INT,
    lmt INT,
    ladprox INT,
    laddist INT,
    diag INT,
    cxmain INT,
    ramus INT,
    om1 INT,
    om2 INT,
    rcaprox INT,
    rcadist INT,
    lvx1 INT,
    lvx2 INT,
    lvx3 INT,
    lvx4 INT,
    lvf INT,
    cathef INT,
    junk INT,
    name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

For some reason I keep getting the following utterly unhelpful error:

> "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',
> thalrest INT,
> tpeakbps INT,
> tpeakbpd INT,
> dummy INT,
> trestbpd INT,
> exang INT,
> ' at line 33"

I am using mysql Ver 8.0.27 for macos11 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL) and am using the database I want to create the table in (`USE cleveland;` outputs "Database changed"). I am also a root user so permissions shouldn't be the reason for this issue.
Does anyone have any insight into what I am doing wrong? I apologize for any mistakes or omitted information in this post, I am a student and am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried it and it works for me

Comment: The query works in version 8.0.25 on linux 5.10.74-gentoo as well.

Comment: Hmm, I just quit mysql and tried it again but no luck, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: How exactly are you writing the query, mysql command line client?  Are you copy-pasting it from somewhere, is there maybe some hidden/funny characters?

Comment: @Don'tPanic You were completely right, there was a hidden character that I was pasting in that was not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, in my text editor (vscode) somehow there is a single character tab which looks exactly like a space but is not recognized by mysql. The only way you can view it is by highlighting the text:

[highlighted text in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmkoJ.png)

By looking at the last input, eventually I realized the input did not include a space between the value name and the data type.